# Is there any way that I can use variables while changing the the properties of document.getElemtentbyId(").style in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way that I can change the properties in `document.getElementbyId.style` with a variable that I received from the Parameters of the function?

```
function toggleFunction(elementId, property1, property2) {
    let element = document.getElementById(elementId)
    if (element.style.display == property1) {
        element.style.display = property2
    } else {
        element.style.display = property1
    }
}
```

The above code is not giving me the desired result.
Is there a way that I can use variable values that I got from parameters for writing Properties?

Comment: That should work. Please post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Yes, you can use variable, exactly like you've used in your code. If you defined "_the desired results_", we might be able to fix your issue.

Comment: Remember that `element.style` doesn't include styles inherited from CSS, it only has inline styles. Use `getComputedStyle()` to get inherited styles.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't catch what you need but its simple. Your code should work good if you use correct arguments for you func. But don't use "element" name twice. That is bad practise

```
const elementId = 'your-element-id'
const property1 = 'none'
const property2 = 'block'

const element = document.getElementById(elementId)
element.style.display = property1 // Set element's display = 'none'
```

The same way for another style properties:

```
element.style.width = '50%'
element.style.color = '#ff0000'
element.style.marginTop = '14px'
```

Read more -> [HTML DOM Style Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp)